# I can't sign out from firebase, still user is not null

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Execute this code:

```
 firebase.auth().signOut();
```

Although user logout, `user.getIdToken` generate the new token. user is not null.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
        user.getIdToken(true).then((token) => console.log(token)).catch((err) => { console.log(err)});
    } else {

    }
});
```

Comment: share error screenshot ....!

Comment: there is no error. Problem is that, although user logout, user.getIdToken generate the new token.   When user logout,  user object have to blank. firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => console.log(user))
//Log: null
But althoug user logout , user is not null.

Comment: are you sure the user is signing out? `firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
  console.log('Signed Out');
}, function(error) {
  console.error('Sign Out Error', error);
});` try this to be sure

Comment: catch error. Although user login, firbase.auth().currentUser = null :/ @PeterHaddad

Comment: if you sure that user logged out, give null to user. If not sure, and catch something just share

Comment: are you from Turkey? @Ozan

Comment: app probably crashed afterwards. That's what happened to me

Answer (score -2):

firebase.auth().signOut() signs out the user both in Android and in iOS. I tested it. CurrentUser should be null (nil in iOS) afterwards. If it didn't, your other codes may have crashed the app or activity preventing that process to finish - that's what happened to me.

No need for onAuthStateChanged.